# Are there any note-taking applications that allows for typing and drawing on a touch screen?

Tags: software-recommendation, touchscreen

I've looked at recommendations for other note-taking applications, but none of them have the feature I need. I would really like a note taking app that allows me to type up my notes, but also allows me to use a touchscreen to write out or draw equations or diagrams. Is there any app like this?

Comment: Like equations, pictures, graphs. Just really fast pictures that would be easier to make drawing it instead of getting programs to make it for me

Answer (score 0):

you could try using image editing software such as gimp or krita. krita has a touchscreen version as well. It is called krita sketch
https://krita.org/item/krita-on-the-go-krita-sketch/

Comment: you could have this open while typing notes in libre office. then copy the pics into the document

Comment: I tried libre office for not taking. It was okay, i just took pictures and uploaded it onto there, but it just got so slow if i added lots of things to it. I even modified it. No Java, allocated more ram to it, nothing.